# Emails in Thunderbird disappear on repair

Tags: thunderbird

I have a (large) number of strangly corrupted local folders in Thunderbird.  As far as I am aware, all emails in these folders are currently displaying correctly. They are shown in the folders, and I can open them and read them.  However, all or almost all emails in these folders disappear if I apply any of the following operations to the containing folder:

- repair folder *(context menu > Properties > Repair folder)*
- export folder as mbox-file and reimport it *(using ImportExportTools addon)*
- close Thunderbird, delete *.msf file associated with the folder, and restart Thunderbird

(I've also tried migrating the folders to Evolution, in several different ways, but this is perhaps a different story.  The best result I have been able to obtain is equally strange:  I can see the migrated emails on the disk, but Evolution displays the folder as empty.)

Does anybody have an idea what might be going on?  Is there a way I can “repair” my folders without losing my emails?

```
system:        Ubuntu 14.04
software:      Thunderbird 45.3.0

Account Settings 
  > Local Folders 
    > DiskSpace: 
      Don't delete any messages.
    > Message Storage Type:  
      file per folder (mbox)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have, meanwhile, found two ways to restore these folders to a state in which they are stable under the operations described in the question:

**Option A:  move folders to an imap server & back** (using drag & drop)

[Initially, I had incorrectly reported that this does not help.  But this was because I had inadvertedly been using a pop-server and other local mail storage instead.  Sorry.]

**Option B:  export & reimport emails as eml-files** (using ImportExportTools addon)

[This option I had already reported on in my original question, but it has several drawbacks:
(a) I need to do this for each folder manually, 
(b) Marking emails as read is no longer functional after this process:  they are sporadically reverted to “unread“ status.  In particular, all emails get reverted to “unread” status when I “repair” the folder.]

If anybody knows what is actually going on here, and how the problem is “supposed” to be fixed, I’d still be interested.